# Disable postback for buttonfields/commandfield in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a List of objects which is databound to a gridview.
The gridview has a delete button attached to the row.

I need the List of objects to persist through clicks (as if working offline)
I don't wish to use sessions or cookies or viewstates

Current behaviour:
List has 4 items => delete 1 item => List has 3 Items => delete 1 item (POSTBACK) list gets regenerated with 4 items then deletes 1.

```
class Emails
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public Emails(string _Address)
    {
        Email = _Address;
    }
}


        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ListOfEmails = new List<Emails>();
            ListOfEmails.Add(new Emails("1@a.com"));
            ListOfEmails.Add(new Emails("2@a.com"));
            ListOfEmails.Add(new Emails("3@a.com"));
            ListOfEmails.Add(new Emails("4@a.com"));

            GridView1.DataSource = ListOfEmails;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

    protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        string EmailToBeDeleted = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Text;
        ListOfEmails.Remove(ListOfEmails.Find(L => L.Email == EmailToBeDeleted));
        GridView1.DataSource = null;
        GridView1.DataSource = ListOfEmails;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

aspx:

```
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email Address" />
        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Delete" HeaderText="Action2" 
            ShowHeader="True" Text="Delete" />    
        <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" DeleteImageUrl="~/delete.gif" 
            ShowDeleteButton="True" />
```

"I have 2 delete buttons at the moment"

Comment: place them within updatepanel?

Comment: that would only suppress the post back or make them invisible i wish to disable them until i explicitly order a post back.

Answer (score 0):

Webpages are stateless.  If you reload a page, all controls and data are recreated.  This is why we use things like Viewstates and Session variables to persist data across post/gets.  Using other technologies like caching and update panels only hide the fact that you are using view states.  The only option I can think of would be to read/write to some data source (database or flat file like XML) but this is more overhead then using viewstates or sessions.  Maybe if you explain your reasoning for wanting to avoid these options we can come up with a solution?

Comment: I wish not to use Session/ViewState because i wish to do it another way.

I wish to do it like you would do on desktop .net

That is work on the list (in memory) without page post backs and only do them when required

Comment: Desktop applications and web applications are fundamentally different.  Desktop apps allow for seamless communication between the GUI and server/application code.  As I mentioned above, HTTP is stateless.  This means there is no communication between the server code and the code that is rendered on the users web browser.  This communication is accomplished with viewstates, sessions, etc.  You can use these objects to make the application seem like an desktop app but it wont really be one.

Comment: I do understand that, i solved it by using Session for persistance.

The behaviour i wanted though was to mimic desktop application but not using post back until you are done i.e. like a save button

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you are saying.  So, you want to be able to delete a row from the gridview without doing a postback (ie: through javascript of jQuery) then update the datasource when the user click the "Submit" button?

Comment: This really isn't advisable as the gridview was not intended to work that way and may cause unexpected problems.  That being said, here are some articles I found: http://dotnetsavvyblog.blogspot.com/2007/11/all-of-us-have-at-some-point-or-other.html and http://forums.asp.net/t/1299021.aspx